# Failed to create a file system

Tags: installation, filesystem

My DELL inspiron 1545 is having no operating system now. While I am trying to install UBUNTU 12.10 from usb, I am getting this error

```
 "the ext4file system creation in partition#1 of SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda) failed"
```

What should I do to complete my installation successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you got a corrupted download, or that the burn was bad. You can check the iso you dowloaded by testing its md5sum to make sure it is good.

[HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem. tried at first edubuntu...installed. than lubuntu...the above mentioned problem. than edubuntu gain...now same problem. when i switch it on without installation-usbstick only the cursor shows up. the installation process is fine until typing name and password etc.? could it be physically the hard disk